# Python: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for arithmetic

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error

This is my first question on stack overflow, please comment on how I could improve on asking questions.

This is what I feel is the pertinent part of my code.

```
#import libraries
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

#leapfrog method
def orbit(m1=1.0e30, m2=1.0e24, a=1.0e11, e=0.1):

    #conditions
    G=6.67*e-11
    q=m1/m2
    m=m1+m2
    r0=(1-e)*a/(1+q)
    v0=1/(1+q)sqrt((1+e)/(1-e)*G*m/a)
```

When I import my code I receive an error:

```
import hw5redo
  File "hw5redo.py", line 12
    r0 = (1-e)*a/(1+q)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also when I comment it out of my code I receive:

```
import hw5redo
  File "hw5redo.py", line 12
    #r0=(1-e)*a/(1+q)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought that comments should not even be considered syntaxErrors because they are for the user only.

Comment: You seem to have some unprintable characters at the beginning of your code (you can see how they manifest when you click "edit" on your post here). Ensure that your .py file contains only text with code.

Comment: About how to ask question, I recommend the post from the StackOverflow master: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: `(1+q)sqrt(..)` is not valid python code. It should be `(1+q)*sqrt(..)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rth is right, please check the code below, you should use the * before the sqrt function:

```
def orbit(m1=1.0e30, m2=1.0e24, a=1.0e11, e=0.1):

    G = 6.67 * e - 11
    q = m1 / m2
    m = m1 + m2
    r0 = (1 - e) * a / (1 + q)
    value = (1 + e) / (1 - e) * G * m / a
    # Note that value is negative in this case, and it will raise a warning
    print value
    v0 = 1 / (1 + q) * sqrt(value)
```

Hope the code helps you.